# How to show one different image in a button toggle when tapped?

Tags: swift, image, button

I have a setting of a Button inside a function in a UIViewController extension. I set the two images for the two different state. But this doesn't change when the button is pressed. How I can fix this?

I tried all the solutions provided here.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension UIViewController {

    func addSortAndWeatherButton(sortAction: Selector, weatherAction: Selector){

    let sortButton: UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButton.ButtonType.custom)

    sortButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "sort-near.png"), for: .normal)
    sortButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "sort-rating.png"), for: .selected)

    sortButton.addTarget(self, action: sortAction, for: .touchUpInside)
    sortButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 25, height: 25)
    let sortBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: sortButton)

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = sortBarButton
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your button action `sortAction` you need to set your button to selected state. Something like:

```
sender.isSelected.toggle()
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, I want to change favorite button icon according to status. My solution create two different button. According to status, code change `custom view` of `UIBarButtonItem` .

```
var isFavoriteButtonFilled = false

lazy var favoriteButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
    button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "navHeart"), for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(favoriteUser), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()

lazy var filledFavoriteButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
    button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "navHeartFilled"), for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(favoriteUser), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()

@objc private func favoriteUser() {

    let favoriteItem: UIBarButtonItem

    if isFavoriteButtonFilled {
        favoriteItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: favoriteButton)
    } else {
        favoriteItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: filledFavoriteButton)
    }

    isFavoriteButtonFilled.toggle()
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [favoriteItem]
}
```